# write an enumeration in TextView that needs leading spaces

Tags: android, textview

I would like to define strings in xml that look like this and are just put in a TextView:

```
1. this is my first paragraph. Where
   it is important that it is correctly
   aligned.

2. and this would be the second one
   which is aligned
```

If I just write:

```
 <string name="infoHelp">1. this is my first paragraph. Where\n    it is important that it is correctly\n   aligned.</string>
```

Where I insert whitespaces after \n they are trimmed. Would would be the best way to do this?

Please no html solution, I cannot use it in this case!

Thanks very much

EDITED from /n to \n

ADDED this layout file:

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent"
         android:weightSum="10" android:orientation="horizontal">

....

        <TextView android:id="@+id/info_help" 
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
            android:layout_height="380sp"
            android:text ="@string/InfoHelp"
            android:layout_marginTop = "13sp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="12sp"
            android:layout_marginRight="12sp"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textSize="13sp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/Info_title"
        >
            </TextView>

    </RelativeLayout>
```

and the strings file is just as I have shown. There is no chance I get any leading whitespaces from my strings file - I have tried to insert extra whitespaces anywhere, but they are ALWAYS trimmed. No matter where I put them.

I just read somewhere that this is XML - but you told me that it works in your case - I am confused now???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to work fine in a textview like

```
textView.setText("1. this is my first paragraph. Where\n    it is important that it is correctly\n    aligned.");
```

The only thing I changed was '/n' to '\n'

Comment: sorry, I just mistyped. I meant \n. But as I said, I need it in an xml file for localization purposes and I have many languages. Putting it in code would dramatically increase the complexity.

Comment: Hmm strange. I put the text in the string's xml file and it works. I can think anything to cause this. Try cleaning the project sometime it just fixes everything. Otherwise put your code it help some one to find what going wrong.

Comment: I found a way around it. Just put the complete string in quotes in the xml file... Thanks blessenm for your ideas!

Comment: Isn't that how it already was. Trimming only happens at the beginning and end of the string which confused me. Anyway good that you worked it out.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I think there is a way. You can get your string from XML in code as a char array. Make a new String, then where ever you get \n, put the characters to new string up till this \n and append required spaces after \n. And append rest of the char array using same logic to the newly made string and apply it to TextView. May be that's not a perfect way but you can give it a try it.